# Show that the theory of $ (\mathbb{Z}, s)$ has quantifier elimination.

Tags: model-theory, quantifier-elimination

I am trying to solve Exercise 3.4.3 from Marker's *Model Theory: An introduction* which states

> a) Show that the Theory of $(\mathbb{Z},s)$ has quantifier elimination, where $s(x)=x+1$. Show that this theory is strongly minimal and that $acl(A)$ is the set of elements "reachable" from A.
>
> b) Show that the theory of $(\mathbb{N},s)$ does not have quantifier elimination.

First off, I'm not sure I understand what the language is. Can we assume that the language includes $+$, as a function, and $1$ as a constant? In that case every element is definable.

My idea to prove this is to show that for every $\exists x\varphi(\bar{y},x) $-formula, where $\varphi$ is a conjunction of atomic formulas, is equivalent to a quantifier-free formula (modulo the theory). I think that by these formulas it is only possible to denote a specific integer, or an element of a cofinite set. If this is true, the theory is strongly minimal but I'm not sure how to show the last claim nor if my interpretation of the question is correct.

Comment: I take it as meaning that $s$ is the only function, and there are no constants, but alas I do not have the book to hand.

Comment: "Can we assume that the language includes $+$, as a function, and $1$ as a constant?" No - the notation $(\mathbb{Z},s)$ means that we're considering $\mathbb{Z}$ as a structure in the language $\{s\}$ consisting of a single unary function symbol $s$. The definition $s(x) = x+1$ is just there to tell you how $s$ is interpreted in this structure, $x+1$ is not a term in the language.